# how to make swap permanent in vm?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

I create the ubuntu vm by vagrant. I want to add the swap to vm.

the steps:

```
mkdir /swapfile
cd /swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=swap bs=1024 count=2000000
sudo mkswap -f  swap
sudo swapon swap
add /swapfile/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0 to /etc/fstab
```

It works:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/swapfile$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           489        203        286          0         11         81
-/+ buffers/cache:        110        379
Swap:         1953          0       1953
```

But when i exit the vm, then login, the swap is missing. How to make the swap permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a directory called `/swapfile` and a file called `swap` but in the `/etc/fstab` you refer to `/swapfile/swapfile` instead of `/swapfile/swap`